# FToA: $P(z)$ can be factorized into linear terms $\in \mathbb C$ (it's roots). Then $P(z)$ can be factorised into REAL linear and quadratic terms.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

> By the FTA I know that every non-constant polynomial has at least one
>   root.

Then I can show that it can be factorized into $deg(P(z))$ linear terms.

Now I'm **trying to show** the corollary:

It can be factorized into quadratic, linear terms in $\mathbb R$

I thought about using the fact that complex roots come in pairs. But what about polynomial $z+i=0$, it only has $1$ complex root.

Also, I think I'd have to prove the fact that they DO come in pairs. How can I show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $z+i=0$ has only one complex root, but the correct fact is that the roots of a polynomial with *real coefficients* come in pairs, i.e., if $a+bi$ is a root also $a-bi$ is a root.

From there, your intuition is correct and the idea is exactly associate factor $(z-\alpha)$ with $(z-\overline{\alpha})$ to obtain the quadratic factors.

Comment: Will I need to prove that they come in pairs? Or can I simply use that statement?

Comment: That part is easy: if $\alpha$ is a complex root of a polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, then we have $p(\alpha)=0$ and $p(\overline{\alpha})=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k (\overline{\alpha})^k=\sum_{k=0}^n \overline{a_k \alpha^k}=\overline{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \alpha^k}=\overline{0}=0$.